# Is there a tool to directly edit the contents of a Jackrabbit repository?

Tags: jackrabbit

I have a file system based Jackrabbit repository which I would like to view and edit directly. Is there an existing tool that allows me to view/edit/delete/add nodes directly?

Comment: For whats it worth it took me a day to write a swing app that could view/edit/delete nodes and I'm not even a swing developer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jackrabbit itself currently has no built-in general-purpose JCR explorer, but there are some open source options available. [This article](http://dev.day.com/microsling/content/blogs/main/jcrtools.html) gives a good overview, and the [JCRLinks](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/JcrLinks) page on the Jackrabbit wiki has a [section about such tools](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/JcrLinks#head-b923fd013974428bd9d78e4c6adb6709e6c2a4f8).

The best web-based one is probably the [JCR Explorer](http://www.jcr-explorer.org/index.html). And for use in Eclipse, [Day's Eclipse plugin](http://www.day.com/eclipse/) offers most features (it also supports Jackrabbit).

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. That's really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

If it's behind a WebDAV server, mount it as a file system.

Comment: Ah, i wish it were behind a webdav server, but in this case it's not. I'm hoping there's a direct tool to examine the contents of the repository.

Answer (score 2):

[SPT JCR Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sptjcrmanager/):

> A simple web application used to view and manage Java Content Repositories