# Does anybody know a good and easy JCR UI management Tool?

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I'm importing massive data into a JackRabbit JCR repository. A good UI management tool to visualize the JCR repository would be great to check if the imported data is in a good layout, and also would make my life as developer easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the creator of the JCR Controller. The webstart version is limited and I will update it soon. The best way is to checkout the sourcecode directly from sourceforge.
It will be also be a good moment to update the Controller.

Comment: JCR Controller (version 0.72, downloaded from sourceforge) worked fine for JackRabbit 2.2 after modifying classpath: replace  jackrabbit-jcr-rmi-1.3.jar by jackrabbit-jcr-rmi-2.2.0.jar and add jcr-2.0.jar

Thank you for such tool!

Comment: Since you are it's creator: The homage gives a 404. :-(

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend you [JCR Controller](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jcrconnector/).

Comment: I already did some tests on JCR Controller. It appears to be the best opensource tool, but it isn't so mature IMHO. I had a few problems visualizing the data. I could not see some nodes.

Answer (score 2):

This was previously answered, see [Is there a tool to directly edit the contents of a Jackrabbit repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382622)

BTW, I wouldn't call that "Graphical Tool", as I'd associate that with some sort of drawing or 3D application. It's rather a "management UI", "browser" or "content explorer".

Comment: I'll try again JCR Explorer. I had a few issues to deploy it on my server, and because of it I just started to try other tools. I already saw the pages on Jackrabbit wiki. The Day plugin seems to be not working on current Eclipse version. Thanks for the help!